# How to add/remove indentation from current line up to the line where a given pattern is found?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change the indentation of a class file in vim so that:

```
class ClassName {
    Q_OBJECT                                                                       
    public:                                                                        
    ClassName(int deviceId = 1);                                                 
    ~ClassName();                                                                

    public slots:                                                                  
        void run();                                                                    
        void connectDevice();                                                          
        void disconnectFromDevice();                                                   
};
```

becomes:

```
class ClassName {
    Q_OBJECT                                                                       
    public:                                                                        
    ClassName(int deviceId = 1);                                                 
    ~ClassName();                                                                

    public slots:                                                                  
    void run();                                                                    
    void connectDevice();                                                          
    void disconnectFromDevice();                                                   
};
```

I known I can use << to remove one indentation level and `<3<` to do it on the next 3 lines, so I tried typing `<f}<` while in line `void run();` to remove one level until the }, but it doesn't work (nothing gets done). What is wrong on this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` searches the current line only for a character. You have to use the search forward command `/`, e.g. `</}` and carriage return.

If you want to avoid to re-indent the line where the search target is, the simplest is to use visual mode: `v\}k<` (where `k` is line-up movement).

Alternatively, if you are on the line of the opening `{`, you can use the matching-parens movement `%`, `<%`.

Note that the `<` operator is documented to work as `[count]<<` or `<{motion}`, although `<[count]<` works too.